# Do shrinkage estimators solve the Neyman-Scott paradox?

Tags: bayesian, consistency, regularization, minimax

I read the following SE question: [What problem do shrinkage methods solve?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20295/what-problem-do-shrinkage-methods-solve) And I wondered if shrinkage estimators provide a consistent estimator of the sample variance in a "mixed-effects" model using fixed effects for cluster adjustment. This is called the Neyman-Scott paradox. [This brief note](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~census/neyscpar.pdf) shows how the MLE is inconsistent and (I think) how conditional likelihood solves the problem. It helps that the solution is an elegant one!

Roughly, the Neyman-Scott paradox illustrates how maximum likelihood estimators can be inconsistent when the parameter space grows with the sample size. From what I understand, shrinkage estimators, like an L2 penalty, also claim to solve these types of problems. They trade an unbiased estimate (of the mean in this case) for a biased one that has much lower variance. But is the resulting estimate of the variance unbiased? I don't know. Nor do I know how one would *show* this.

Do shrinkage estimators solve the Neyman-Scott paradox? If so, how?

Comment: This sounds an interesting notion but could you make it more precise? An objective Bayes approach is for instance unable to "solve" Neyman-Scott.

Comment: @Xi'an Sure but how exactly should I make it more precise? By a "solution" to Neyman-Scott, I mean that the estimator of the variance is a consistent estimator. Is that what you mean?